# HTTP error when trying to access mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hey guys I'm still learning PHP and need help. I have 3 files that require a database.php file to connect to MySQL. when I execute the files only two of them work. For the last file, I get an HTTP error 500.

```
    <?php

      require( 'database.php');  

   // inserting information from the form into the database
   $sql = ("INSERT INTO guestlist (firstName, lastName, phoneNumber,guests,event)
      VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"); 
      // values are prepared to bind
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sssss",$_POST['first_name'],$_POST['last_name'], $_POST['phonenumber'], $_POST['guest'], $_POST['event']);

  $stmt->execute();




   if (!$stmt)// Was not updated
   {
       // shows error


           echo("There was an error with your RSVP.  Please try again.");

           mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
   }

   else //Was updated
   {
           echo("Your RSVP has been completed.");
   }

   //End database connection   
  mysqli_close($con);

   ?>
```

this is my database file that was provided by my professor

```
    <?php

    $myHost = "localhost"; // localhost, do not change this string
    $myUserName = "cmorales";   // CHANGE TO YOUR USERNAME
    $myPassword = "";   // CHANGE TO YOUR PASSWORD
    $myDataBaseName = "cmorales_project"; // CHANGE USERNAME 
       username_project

   $con = mysqli_connect( "$myHost", "$myUserName", "$myPassword", 
       "$myDataBaseName" );

   if( !$con ) // == null if creation of connection object failed
     {
  // report the error to the user, then exit program
     die("connection object not created: ".mysqli_error($con));
     }

   if( mysqli_connect_errno() )  // returns false if no error occurred
     {
 // report the error to the user, then exit program
die("Connect failed: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". 
mysqli_connect_error());
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: There are a bunch of reasons you can get error 500, best thing to do is to check your php error log, if you are using wamp or xampp it should be somewhere in wamp|xampp/log directory...

Comment: I'm using xampp , i'll look into that

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a syntax error in your **database.php**

Cause :
No semicolon end of `username_project` 7th line.

Solution:

remove undefined constant `username_project` on the 7th line.

as @Antonio Teh Sumtin mentioned in the comments, Always check the error log or enable the display error during development.

Comment: I don't have line 7 in my file, that's part of the comment in line 6, it must have moved to line 7 when I copied and pasted the code on here

Comment: Then no syntax error on your code. use this to see exact error. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47641796/2975952